# What's the meaning of "forest air"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

•I sat for a moment, inhaling the fresh **forest air**.

How to interpret this type of phrases correctly ?

I think it could mean - air near the forest.

Comment: There is no special meaning.  What possible meanings do you suppose it could have?

Comment: I think it could mean - air near the forest...

Comment: Why not 'the air _in_ the forest'?

Comment: @KateBunting ,I don't think forest can surround air or air can be inside jungle.(but I have the doubt)

Comment: If air cannot not be **in**  a jungle or forest, what do people and animals breathe in those places?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey in which sense in will be used here?

Comment: We would usually say **in** a jungle, not 'inside'. If I am surrounded by jungle, I am **in** that jungle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With attributive nouns (like "forest" in this example) you should use a mixture of experience and common sense to understand.

Grammatically it just means "air that is associated in some way with the forest".  So how could air be associated with a forest?  Well, a forest is a large area with lots of trees, and between those trees is air. That air is associated with the forest.  We would say that this air is "in" the forest.

That is the meaning.  There's no grammar rule.  Consider "chicken soup"  How might "soup" be associated with "chicken"? I'm sure your guess is right: it is soup *made with* the flesh of a chicken.  What about "tennis racket"  - Yes, it is a racket *used for* playing tennis.

The association is different in each case.  You need to use your knowledge of "air" and "forests"  to interpret how the combination is to be interpreted.

Comment: The cool **night air** wafted in the open windows.     I think night air mean - Air during the night.Is it correct a correct interpretation?

Comment: You know,  there are about a trillion different combinations of noun+noun You have to trust yourself. I'm going to ask you if you actually have any doubt here... Is there any other possible meaning?  Is there any other way that air can be associated with night? Does "air during the night" make sense in context?  If it makes sense and you can't quickly think of an alternative then 99 times out of a 100 you'll be right.

Comment: What's your opinion of its correctness?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to play the game of "what about" in the comments today!  If you really are unsure, and can think of multiple different possibilities.  If you think that "during the night" doesn't make sense, then please ask a new question.#